# Remove duplicated values in a column in dataframe according to ID

Tags: python, pandas

I am performing data cleaning on a dataframe with millions of rows.
It looks like this example:

```
    id   transaction_date  expire_date
0   A    2015-01-01        2015-02-01
1   A    2015-01-01        2015-03-14
2   A    2015-01-01        2015-06-19
3   A    2015-01-01        2015-07-01
4   B    2016-02-02        2016-03-02
5   C    2016-01-01        2016-01-15
```

I would like to remove from row 0 to 3 as so many transactions on the same day with different expire date wouldn't make sense.

I'm thinking of this

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='transaction_date')
```

Is it the correct way?

Comment: If need check 2 columns need `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','transaction_date'])`

Comment: I post a comment in a answer ......`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','transaction_date'],keep=False)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need:

```
#if need check all duplicates per id and transaction_date and drop them
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','transaction_date'],keep=False)
print (df)
  id transaction_date expire_date
4  B       2016-02-02  2016-03-02
5  C       2016-01-01  2016-01-15
```

If need check `expire_date` and remove all dupes rows with all different dates:

```
#check count per group and count unique values in expire_date
df1 = df.groupby(['id', 'transaction_date'])
        .agg({'transaction_date':'size', 'expire_date':'nunique'})
 #get all same count, but remove unique rows
mask = (df1['transaction_date'] == df1['expire_date']) & (df1['transaction_date'] > 1)

#create mask by join to original df
m = df.join(mask.rename('m'), on=['id','transaction_date'])['m']
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: m, dtype: bool

 #last filter by inverting mask by ~
df = df[~m]
print (df)
  id transaction_date expire_date
4  B       2016-02-02  2016-03-02
5  C       2016-01-01  2016-01-15
```